# How do i make DataTable or PaginatedDataTable occupy the full width of its parent Card?

Tags: flutter, datatable

Is there any Widget (SizedBox.expand was mentioned in another issue) or configuration which will enable me to make a DataTable/PaginatedDataTable occupy the full width of its parent Card?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe using ConstrainedBox

new ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                      minWidth: double.infinity
                       ),
                      child: .. ,
                    )

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap your PaginatedDataTable in a Container with full width.

```
    SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
         width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
         child: PaginatedDataTable(
          ...
    ),),);
```

Comment: Good Idea, but now all Columns are stretched over the full display size. This isn't my preferred way of doing that, I want that the last column will fill the available space.